# MsSQL или PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

Какую из этих баз лучше выбрать?
Я пишу сайт на Asp.Net Core.  Вроде-бы более родная база Майкрософта.
Но интересно подключить PostgreSQL, так как с ней раньше работал и она бесплатна.
Напишите Ваше мнение,тесты производительности и отличия этих БД.
Спасибо

Comment: Проблема этого вопроса в том, что он просит о сравнении двух очень крупных продуктов, каждый из которых можно использовать в очень большом спектре задач и каждый из них законфигурить до полной неузнаваемости с разительно разнящимися показателями производительности. Обычно сравнение производится для конкретных случаев, на конкретных данных, на конкретных запросах.

Comment: PostgreSQL очень стабильная и развитая СУБД. Не пожалеете никогда если ее выберете. 
Вообще это хорошо когда люди думают и рассматривают варианты, а не хватают бездумно первый попавшийся MySQL :-)

Answer (score 1):

производительность Microsoft SQL Server и PostgreSQL принципиально не отличается при условии: речь идет о PostgreSQL на Linux. А вот на Windows PostgreSQL ставить не следует

Comment: http://infostart.ru/bitrix/components/infostart/forum.interface/show_file.php?fid=370629&action=download